# One sided limit with $e^x$ and $\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Assuming that $e^{x} \to e^{a}$ and $\sin(x) \to \sin(a)$

evaluate the limit as $$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{e^{x^2+2x-1}}{\sin(x)}$$

To me, based on the first sentence. I could just plug in $a$ and get my limit which does not exist at the point $x=0$ However the back of the book says infinity so I am at a loss as to how to prove this.

This is a real analysis class but this is isn't one of the problems requiring us to prove with definitions but it would be helpful to learn the algebra and the theory. I don't understand as to how I can apply the definition of a function converging to infinity to prove this. Plus I don't see how that could help? How am I supposed to know it goes to infinity

Comment: It is a matter of convention to say "does not exist" or "is infinity" when a limit diverges. This particular limit is equivalent to that of $e^{-1}/x$.

Comment: The initial statements of $e^x \to e^a$ and $\sin(x) \to \sin(a)$ are tantamount to assuming that the functions are continuous. Hence, the limit of the quotient is the quotient of the limits. The top approaches a finite, positive number and the bottom approaches $0$ from the positive side. Hence, the overall limit goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x$ is close enough to $0$, then $-1.1<x^2+2x-1$ so that
$$\exp(-1.1)<\exp(x^2+2x-1)$$

and hence the function in your limit is bounded from below by $\frac{\exp(-1.1)}{\sin x}$ which blows up at $x=0$ since $\sin0=0$.